# How can I put the brand logo in the QR code?

Tags: swift

```
extension CIImage {
   /// Combines the current image with the given image centered.
   func combined(with image: CIImage) -> CIImage? {
  guard let combinedFilter = CIFilter(name: "CISourceOverCompositing") else { return nil }
   let centerTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: extent.midX - (image.extent.size.width / 2), y: extent.midY - (image.extent.size.height / 2))
  combinedFilter.setValue(image.transformed(by: centerTransform), forKey: "inputImage")
 combinedFilter.setValue(self, forKey: "inputBackgroundImage")
   return combinedFilter.outputImage!
   }
}

/// Creates a QR code for the current URL in the given color.
 func qrImage(using color: UIColor, logo: UIImage? = nil) -> CIImage? {
   let tintedQRImage = qrImage?.tinted(using: color)
       guard let logo = logo?.cgImage else {
            return tintedQRImage
    }
     return tintedQRImage?.combined(with: CIImage(cgImage: logo))
 }

 /// Returns a black and white QR code for this URL.
   var qrImage: CIImage? {
       guard let qrFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") else { return nil }
      let qrData = absoluteString.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)
     qrFilter.setValue(qrData, forKey: "inputMessage")

   let qrTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 12, y: 12)
    return qrFilter.outputImage?.transformed(by: qrTransform)
  }
```

I created the qr code in the color I want, but when I put the logo, the logo comes over the qr code and a very ugly image is formed. As in the first picture.How can I create a space in the middle of the qr and put the logo in that space?

```
private func configureQrCode() {
    let qrCodeColor = UIColor.qrColor
    let qrCodeLogo = UIImage(named: "signinlogo")
    guard let qrURLImage = URL(string: QRCodeConstants.qrLink)?.qrImage(using:   qrCodeColor, logo: qrCodeLogo) else { return }
   qrCode.image = UIImage(ciImage: qrURLImage)
 }
```

[![][1]][1]
[![I want it to look like this, but it's like the one above][2]][2]

Comment: How about instead of the transparent background on your logo you have a white circle as its background? Or a white rectangle with rounded corners as a background.

Comment: When I put the logo in a white circle and add it in the middle, there is a problem in reading the qr code. Because the middle of the qr code is closed. :(

Answer (score 1):

QR codes have an [error correction](https://www.qrcode.com/en/about/error_correction.html) feature that you can use to your advantage. Give the logo a white background and put it in the center of the QR code, just make sure the logo isn’t too big or the error correction won’t be able to account for it. If you need an example to follow, use this: https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/qr-code-generation-swift/